# How do I show that $0$ is the $\inf$ of $\left\{\ln(\frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}): n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Considering the set of real numbers:

$$A = \left\{\ln\left(\frac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}\right): n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}.$$

I must prove that $0$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$.

I have completed similar examples to this and know I have to show there exists a sequence converging to $0$ but am struggling to find one and prove that $0$ is the glb for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{2n + \sqrt{n}}{2n - \sqrt{n}} = 1 + \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{2n - \sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: So this would suggest it tends to 1 and therefore the set A converges to 0 as n tends to infinity, therefore 0 is the greatest lower bound?

Comment: Yes, you can apply your favourite test for convergence here to show that this expression tends to $1$. And just to note, since your original question was about greatest lower bounds, and not just about limits, you will also need to show that each term is greater than $1$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the continuity and monotonocity of the function $\ln$, we find that as 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n + \sqrt{n} }{2n - \sqrt{n} } = \lim_{ n \to \infty} \frac{ 2 + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n} } }{ 2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} } } = \frac{ 2 + 0}{ 2 - 0} = 1,
$$
so we find that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \left( \frac{2n + \sqrt{n} }{2n - \sqrt{n} }  \right) = \ln 1 = 0, \tag{0}
$$
and, for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, as 
$$
\begin{align}
&\qquad \frac{ 2 (n+1) + \sqrt{n+1} }{ 2(n+1) - \sqrt{ n+1} } - \frac{2n + \sqrt{n} }{2n - \sqrt{n} } \\ 
&= \frac{ \left( 2 (n+1) + \sqrt{n+1} \right)^2 }{ 4 (n+1)^2 - (n+1) }  - \frac{ \left( 2n + \sqrt{n} \right)^2 }{ 4n^2 - n } \\
&= \frac{ \left( 2 \sqrt{ n+1 } + 1 \right)^2 }{ 4 (n+1) - 1 } - \frac{ \left( 2 \sqrt{n} + 1 \right)^2 }{ 4n -1 } \\
&= \frac{ 4n + 5 + 4 \sqrt{n+1 } }{ 4n + 3 } - \frac{ 4n + 1 + 4 \sqrt{n}  }{ 4n-1  } \\
&= \frac{ (4n-1) \left( 4n + 5 + 4 \sqrt{n+1 } \right) - (4n + 3) \left( 4n + 1 + 4 \sqrt{n}  \right) }{ (4n+3) (4n-1) } \\
&= \frac{ \big( (4n-1) ( 4n + 5 ) - (4n+3) ( 4n + 1)  \big) + \big( 4(4n-1) \sqrt{ n+1}   - 4 (4n+3) \sqrt{n} \big) }{ (4n+3) (4n-1)  } \\
&= \frac{ 2 + 16n \left( \sqrt{ n+1} - \sqrt{ n} \right) - 4 \left( \sqrt{ n+1} + 3\sqrt{ n} \right)  }{ (4n+3) (4n-1) } \\
&= \frac{ 2 + 4 \left( 4 n \left( \sqrt{ n+1} - \sqrt{ n} \right) -  \left( \sqrt{ n+1} + 3\sqrt{ n} \right)  \right) }{ (4n+3) (4n-1) } \\
&> \frac{  4 \left( 4 n \left( \sqrt{ n+1} - \sqrt{ n} \right) -  \left( \sqrt{ n+1} + 3\sqrt{ n} \right)  \right) }{ (4n+3) (4n-1) } \\
&> 0,
\end{align}
$$
because
$$
\begin{align}
&\qquad \left[ 4 n \left( \sqrt{ n+1} - \sqrt{ n} \right) +  \left( \sqrt{ n+1} + 3\sqrt{ n} \right) \right] \left[ 4 n \left( \sqrt{ n+1} - \sqrt{ n} \right) -  \left( \sqrt{ n+1} + 3\sqrt{ n} \right) \right] \\
&= \left( 4 n \left( \sqrt{ n+1} - \sqrt{ n} \right) \right)^2 -  \left( \sqrt{ n+1} + 3\sqrt{ n} \right)^2 \\
&= 16n^2 \left( \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \right)^2 - \left( \sqrt{ n+1} + 3\sqrt{ n} \right)^2  \\ 
&= 16 n^2 \left( 2n + 1 - 2 \sqrt{ n(n+1) } \right) - \left( 4n+1 + 6 \sqrt{ n(n+1) } \right) \\
&= \left( 32 n^3 + 16n^2 - 4n -1 \right) + \left( 32n^2 - 6 \right) \sqrt{ n(n+1) } \\
&= \left( 32 n^3 + 16n^2 - \big( 4n +1 \big) \right) + \left( 32n^2 - 6 \right) \sqrt{ n(n+1) } \\
&> 0,
\end{align}
$$
and also because
$$
\begin{align}
4 n \left( \sqrt{ n+1} - \sqrt{ n} \right) +  \left( \sqrt{ n+1} + 3\sqrt{ n} \right) &= (4n+1) \sqrt{ n+1 } - (4n-3) \sqrt{ n } \\
&> (4n-3) \left( \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n } \right) \\
&> 0
\end{align}
$$
for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Thus we have 
$$
\frac{ 2 (n+1) + \sqrt{n+1} }{ 2(n+1) - \sqrt{ n+1} } > \frac{2n + \sqrt{n} }{2n - \sqrt{n} } 
$$
for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, which implies that 
$$
\ln \left( \frac{ 2 (n+1) + \sqrt{n+1} }{ 2(n+1) - \sqrt{ n+1} } \right) > \ln \left( \frac{2n + \sqrt{n} }{2n - \sqrt{n} } \right) \tag{1}
$$
for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

From (0) and (1) above, we find that, the sequence $$ \left(\ \ln \left( \frac{2n + \sqrt{n} }{2n - \sqrt{n} } \right)  \  \right)_{ n \in \mathbb{N} } $$
is a *strictly increasing* sequence converging to $\ln 1 = 0$. Therefore we can conclude that 
$$
0 = \ln 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \left( \frac{2n + \sqrt{n} }{2n - \sqrt{n} } \right) = \sup \left\{ \ \ln \left( \frac{2n + \sqrt{n} }{2n - \sqrt{n} } \right) \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\},
$$
as required.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: The beginning of your answer and the end of your answer are contradictory. Presumably you want to show that the sequence is strictly decreasing to 0.

Comment: @Hayden thanks for pointing out the mistakes in my proof. I've made some edits. Can you please have a look at my post once again? I'm sure the proof is correct now.

Comment: $[4n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})+(\sqrt{n+1}+3\sqrt{n})][4n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})+(\sqrt{n+1}+3\sqrt{n})]$ should be $[4n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})-(\sqrt{n+1}+3\sqrt{n})][4n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})+(\sqrt{n+1}+3\sqrt{n})]$. You might want to point out that this calculation and the following calculation are because you're multiplying $\frac{4(4n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})-(\sqrt{n+1}+3\sqrt{n}))}{(4n+3)(4n-1)}$ by $\frac{4n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})+(\sqrt{n+1}+3\sqrt{n})}{4n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})+(\sqrt{n+1}+3\sqrt{n})}$. You also say "strictly increasing" instead of "strictly decreasing" towards the end.

Comment: @Hayden I've made an edit to my post. Can you please have a look now?

Answer (score 0):

From Saaqib Mahmood, for the property of being strictly increasing of the elements in $\mathbb{A}$, I think **g.l.b.** of $\mathbb{A}$ should be $\log 3$?, I will use $\log$ for the natural logarithm. As we see that $$\log 3=\log\left(\dfrac{2+\sqrt{1}}{2-\sqrt{1}}\right)\le\log\left(\dfrac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ for all $n\ge 1$

---

**Edited:** I think he was wrong as $$\left(\dfrac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}\right)=1+\dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{n}-1}$$
which is seen as a decreasing sequence. And from now on, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\log\left(\dfrac{2n+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}\right)=0$, with the decrease in value of the elements, we then have $\inf\mathbb{A}=0$ as desired.